# moving object from listbox to another listbox in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, listboxitem

How i can moving object( that is include name and id) from listbox to another listbox and save it?
i wrote this:

```
 if (lstActivity.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {

                int intSelectedIndex = lstActivity.SelectedIndex;
                if (intSelectedIndex >= 0)
                {

 listbox.Items.Add(((Parking_Services.Activity)lstActivity.SelectedItem).ActivityName);

                    lstActivity.Items.RemoveAt(intSelectedIndex);
                }
            }
```

it is worked but when i want save this (after clicked button), it get exception : " can not cast syste.string to (Parking_Services.Activity)."

```
  private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int intActivityID;
            Parking_Services.Service1 ii = new Parking_Services.Service1();
            for (int i = 0; i <= listbox.Items.Count; i++)                                            //save item from listbox is wrong
            {
                intActivityID = ((Parking_Services.Activity)listbox.Items[i]).ActivityID;
                string strMessage = ii.AllowUserActivityByType(intUserTypeID, intActivityID, FrmLogin.intUserId);

            }
```

Comment: Is the proposed fix working? If so, can you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line...

```
intActivityID = ((Parking_Services.Activity)listbox.Items[i]).ActivityID;
```

...fails, because the items in `listbox` are `String`s and not `Parking_Services.Activity`s. And they are `String`s because, you add `String`s in the line...

```
listbox.Items.Add(((Parking_Services.Activity)lstActivity.SelectedItem).ActivityName);
```

I suppose the `ActivityName` property is a `String`. So there is a design error in either of those two lines.

---

I suggest the following fix: Add the whole `Parking_Services.Activity` objects to `listbox`...

```
listbox.Items.Add((Parking_Services.Activity)lstActivity.SelectedItem);
```

...and override `ToString()` in the `Parking_Services.Activity` class, so `listbox` displays them correctly:

```
public class Activity
{
    ...

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ActivityName;
    }
}
```

A `ListBox` always calls `ToString()` on the `object`s passed to it, when painting their list entries. So, by overriding `ToString()`, you can control how your `Parking_Services.Activity`s are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're not adding an object of type `Parking_Services.Activity` to the list box, but the `ActivityName` of the selected `Parking_Services.Activity` in the following line:

```
listbox.Items.Add(((Parking_Services.Activity)lstActivity.SelectedItem).ActivityName);
```

I'd expect this to be a string. Instead you may try this:

```
listbox.Items.Add(lstActivity.SelectedItem);
```

Given that the item in `lstActivity` is of type `Parking_Services.Activity`.